# NL does not see the extension built with NetBeans

Tags: netlogo

I have compiled my extension with NetBeans and the compiling worked fine, I have included a manifest file which is present in the final jar:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Class-Manager: it.unibo.ai.Manager
Extension-Name: DialogueSimulatorExt
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.5
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_65
NetLogo-Extension-API-Version: 6.0
```

And my jar, named DialogueSimulatorExt.jar, is in the folder DialogueSimulatorExt, this latter one is in the same folder as my NL model.

So far so good, but when I try to load the extension within my model, I get prompted to the message "Go to download site for NetLogo extension"

I don't understand what the problem might be, since there is no hint apart from a generic "I don't find it" - even though it's there... what are common reasons for this behavior?

This is my DefaultClassManager:

```
package it.unibo.ai;

import asp4j.solver.object.Filter;
import asp4j.solver.object.ObjectSolver;
import org.nlogo.api.*;

public class Manager extends DefaultClassManager {

    public static String rulefile_clingo = null;
    public static Filter filter = null;
    public static ObjectSolver solver = null;
    public static ProblemSentences ps = null;

    @Override
    public void load(PrimitiveManager primitiveManager) {

        primitiveManager.addPrimitive("setup-solver", new SetupSolver());
        primitiveManager.addPrimitive("setup-beliefs", new SetupInitialBeliefs());
        primitiveManager.addPrimitive("dialogue", new AgentDialogue());

    }

}
```

This is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>it.unibo.ai</groupId>
<artifactId>DialogueSimulatorExt</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nlogo</groupId>
        <artifactId>netlogo</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.nlogo</groupId>
                <artifactId>parser</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.picocontainer</groupId>
        <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-parser-combinators_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.parboiled</groupId>
        <artifactId>parboiled_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>agentdialogues</groupId>
        <artifactId>agentdialogues</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asp4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>asp4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>typesafereleases</id>
        <name>typesafe-releases</name>
        <url>http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>bintraynetlogoNetLogoJVM</id>
        <name>bintray-netlogo-NetLogo-JVM</name>
        <url>https://dl.bintray.com/netlogo/NetLogo-JVM/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<name>DialogueSimulatorExt</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                </archive>
            </configuration>            
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: The name of the Class-Manager in the manifest should be the name of the class that extends `DefaultClassManager` in your java code. Could you share at least the start of the java code?

Comment: sure thing, I have updated the question

Comment: Did you drop your  DialogueSimulatorExt into Netlogo's extensions directory?

Comment: nope, the folder of my extension is on the same level of my model

Comment: Shouldn't it be in /Applications/NetLogo X.X/extensions/?

Comment: good, perfect! it works... write this as an answer I'll be happy to accept it

Comment: @SethTissue, The documentation says "To use our example extension, put the example folder in the NetLogo extensions folder, or in the same directory as the model that will use the extension." https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions-API . This may be a bug that it doesn't actually check the same model directory.

Comment: I think so @SethTissue, now that the folder is in the NL extensions folder, it works fine...

Comment: @mattsap I don't work on NetLogo anymore. you would have to report the problem at https://github.com/netlogo/netlogo/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the `DialogueSimulatorExt` directory in your Netlogo's extension folder: `/Applications/NetLogo X.X/extensions/`